# Why value null after converting in int in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey I am working in android kotlin. I am getting double value in the form of string from server. I am converting that value in Int and checking that value is not null using **toIntOrNull()**. But I am getting 0 all the time.

Value coming from server

```
"value": "79.00"
```

My Data class

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Detail(
    val value: String? = null,
) : Parcelable {
    val valueInDouble by lazy {
        value?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: Double.NaN
    }
    val valueInInt by lazy {
        value?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
    }
}
```

whenever I print the value of **valueInInt** in console it returns **0**. I know that 0 is coming because of `toIntOrNull()` but my value is coming from server which is not null. But I don't understand why this is happening. Can someone guide me please?

**Expected Output**

`79`

**Actual Output**

`0`

Comment: That is because 0 is default value of an int or double

Comment: I know that default value is 0. But my value coming from server is `79.00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the String value has a decimal in it, it cannot be parsed as an integer, so `toIntOrNull()` will return null.

You should parse as a Double and then convert the Double to an Int based on whatever type of rounding is appropriate for your use case.

```
val valueInInt by lazy {
    value?.toDoubleOrNull()?.roundToInt() ?: 0
}
```